# Problem in calling the function panelvar from the library after being installed

Tags: r, gwt, package, regression, panel

I was working with the panelvar package, that I have installed today.I created a new R script, and ran library(panelvar) and got the following error:

> library(panelvar)
>   Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘panelvar’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
>    there is no package called ‘hms’

In fact, I had already installed the package:

> install.packages("panelvar")
>   WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:
>
> https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
>   trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.6/panelvar_0.5.2.zip'
>   Content type 'application/zip' length 2565900 bytes (2.4 MB)
>   downloaded 2.4 MB
>
> package ‘panelvar’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
>
> The downloaded binary packages are in
>       C:\Users\JSamridhi\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp0GEDNw\downloaded_packages

When I try uploading the package, I get the same error again. I tried deleting the file from the library using .libpath and reinstalled the whole thing but its just not working.

Comment: try `install.packages("hms")`. It seems to be an uninstalled dependency

Comment: You could also install Rtools by following the instructions in the error (https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/).

Comment: The best place now to ask for GWT questions is to join https://gitter.im/gwtproject/gwt